# Disable the "cell connection" on the fly (use as PDA mostly)

Tags: lumia, settings

I never had a windows phone. Since I'm not too fond of Android or iPhones the thought of getting a windows phone has crossed my mind. (I only have a 'feature cell phone' right now)
Because it often bugs me not to have a camera with me and some other niceties smartphones have.
But I am not interested in 1) wasting battery for what I mostly do not need: being connected to the "cell", i.e. having the actual phone functionality running. and 2) being interruptable by calls and location-tracked all the time.
I.e. most of the time I'd like the connection to the phone service provider *off*, and use all the media, calendar etc functionality, and only enable the actual phone part when needed.

I am aware that this must seem an arcane request, but unlike most people today, I do not like being available and interrupted by calls 24/7 - so my current feature phone is off most of the time. If I buy a smartphone to get all the modern goodies, it's only if I can keep it that way without also not being able to use said goodies.

Is this possible at all with a nokia lumia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible on all Windows Phone. Just turn on the [airplane mode](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/connectivity/whats-airplane-mode).

> Airplane mode is a setting on your phone that lets you turn off the cellular connection, Wi-Fi, FM radio, Bluetooth, and near field communication (NFC) sharing on your phone simultaneously. You can still use other apps that don't require a cellular connection, including ones that let you listen to music or watch videos.
>
> While you're in airplane mode, you can still turn on Wi-Fi, FM radio,
>   Bluetooth, and NFC sharing individually. Cellular remains off until
>   you turn off airplane mode.

On Windows Phone 8.1, you can quickly turn on and off the feature by using the quick actions on the [action center](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/notifications-and-quick-actions).

Comment: most excellent!